# How to get the iso2 language code from the locale language code

Tags: ios, iphone, nslocale

I want to get the language code as 3 letters(ISO 639-2 Code) like "ENG","SPN","abk" etc.

But from the `NSLocale` I'm receiving the language code as "en" etc. By using the code `NSLocale.current.languageCode`. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Strictly spoken `iso2` is a two letter code.

Comment: @vadian do u have any solution for this?

Comment: I guess you have to create a mapping table (for example via `NSLocalizedString`)